# Can't get the Instagram page

Tags: python, server, python-requests, instagram

On the locale, everything turns out to give the desired page, but on the server not, the code is the same. Both have `<html lang = "en" class = "no-js not-logged-in client-root">`, but on the locale it gives the user page, and on the server the page for registration. How do I fix this?
`?__a=1` only works on locale

code:

```
import requests


POSTFIX = '?__a=1'
HEADERS = {
    'accept' : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_json(url):
    page = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
    print(page.text)
```

How can I get the desired page on the server?

Comment: where is `POSTFIX` used?

Comment: when calling get_json but what's with it, what without it, I get a page for authorization